# awk print condition

Tags: awk

When i was debugging a file which was written by others, I found one line

```
psql -U user -h $2 -p 5432 mydb -c "set search_path=$3;$4" | awk 'NR>3 {print l} {l=$0}'
```

I don't know what

```
awk 'NR>3 {print l} {l=$0}'
```

does this line actually do. Can anyone explain what does this line mean? `{print l}`

Answer (score 7):

A simpler input to explain the command:

```
$ seq 6 | awk 'NR>3 {print l} {l=$0}'
3
4
5
```

- `NR` is a special variable that has the value of current record number (same as line number in this case)

  - so `NR>3` means line number greater than 3
- `{l=$0}` this is saving contents of current line (special variable `$0`) to a user defined variable `l`
- `NR>3 {print l}` when the condition is true, print contents of variable `l`

So, effectively, this code prints all lines from input except first two lines and the last line.

Comment: and of course you should never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates the code.